# Script for running Docker commands

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently, I'm using bash script in order to execute docker commands.
For example `docker-compose up -d` is just `command start` inside the terminal and etc.
I have a lot of commands like this to start/stop/restart/execute some commands inside a container and etc.
Everything is working fine, but the problem is with the bash file there are too many if/else for all the commands. I'm trying to find another script language to do this, but not sure which will be cleaner(better to write). Does someone else use something similar?
I was thinking to use Python, but it needs to be something that requests a minimum work from the user side. The idea is just to download the docker repo and start using the commands that's why I'm using bash for now.

Comment: Please provide a specific use case, and a specific question. You're too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Python is an extremely good choice.  The syntax is very easy to pick up, and there are many modules/libraries for infrastructure work.

Python is one of the most popular languages in the Ops/Devops world, so there will also be plenty of help online.